# R dataframe column creation with mutate and webchem::get_cid() function based on the first column string

Tags: r, dplyr, webchem

I'm stuck on a problem, let's say we have a 1 column dataframe `dfCHEM`

```
CHEM_NAME
Aspirin
Captopril
(...)
```

I want to create a second column based on the string of the first using `webchem::get_cid()`

```
CHEM_NAME    CID
Aspirin      2244
Captopril    44093
(...)
```

I try this code which doesn't work:

```
dfCHEM %>%
    mutate(CID=get_cid(CHEM_NAME)[[1]])
```

I'm convinced that it's related to the use of a `get_cid()` function inside the mutate which doesn't retrieve `CHEM_NAME` string value at the corresponding row, but i don't know how to correct this in an efficient manner.

Comment: Remove `[[1]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `rowwise` to your code to force the operation to each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(webchem)

dfCHEM %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(CID = get_cid(CHEM_NAME)[[1]]) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   CHEM_NAME   CID
#       <chr> <int>
# 1   Aspirin  2244
# 2 Captopril 44093
```

Or use `lapply` and `unlist`.

```
dfCHEM %>%
  mutate(CID = unlist(lapply(CHEM_NAME, get_cid)))

#   CHEM_NAME   CID
# 1   Aspirin  2244
# 2 Captopril 44093
```

**DATA**

```
dfCHEM <- read.table(text = "CHEM_NAME
Aspirin
                     Captopril",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: `dfChem %>% mutate(CID = sapply(get_cid(CHEM_NAME), \`[[\`, 1))` works without rowwise, so there's only one call to get_cid. I guess `unlist`-`lapply` is unsafe if get_cid might return a vector for each element. Alternately, just use `first=TRUE` from the docs...

Comment: @Frank Good suggestion. If there are more than one return values per `CID`. The safest way is probably just `dfCHEM %>% mutate(CID=get_cid(CHEM_NAME))` and store the information as a list column in the data frame for further analysis.